# How to make area behind transparent color not interactable/clickable in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, jetbrains-compose

Consider that this composable, which acts as a "Dialog", is being drawn *in front* the root application:

[image: screenshot showing the composables]

I tried to simulate this dialog by making it fit the entire screen and making its root container have a basic `background(Color.Gray.copy(alpha = 0.5f)` modifier.

However, even it is in front still being possible to interact with that top buttons.

My question is if there's a "direct" way to "disable" interactions of a particular composable tree to avoid passing parameters (such as "clickable") to all affected composables?

I thought doing something like:

- take a "screenshot" from the area behind the alpha color;
- draw the screenshot as an Image;
- then draw the in-front composable (in my example, the "dialog").

However, I don't know how worth this is to implement or even how to take that "screenshot".

Also, may be an way to handle this using something relatad to `remember compostion state` or so on.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can have a Box that consumes click events without click feedback:

```
val interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
Box(
    modifier = modifier
        .background(
            color = MaterialTheme.colors.surface.copy(alpha = .4f)
        )
        .clickable(
            onClick = {
                if (dismissOnTouchOutside) {
                    onDismiss()
                }
            },
            interactionSource = interactionSource,
            indication = null
        ),
    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
) {
    // content here
}
```

Comment: Perfect! `interactionSource` saved me!

Comment: If you need this often, you can make it an extension function on Modifier: 
`fun Modifier.preventClickThrough() = composed {
    this.clickable(
        indication = null,
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() }
    ) {}
}`

Comment: Really great, @AndersUllnæss

Answer (score 1):

Use this simple extension to request focus for your current overlay

```
fun Modifier.requestFocus(): Modifier = composed {
    this.clickable(
        interactionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
        indication = null
    ) {}
}
```

Usage:

```
Box(
    modifier = Modifier
        .requestFocus()
        .fillMaxSize()
        .background(AppColors.upcoming_overlay)
)
```